# maven-dependency-plugin get all multi module project's dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a maven multi module project **A**. This project has the sub modules **B and C**.

Now, I want to use the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) plugin to get all the dependencies of **A, B and C**, but without specifying **A, B and C** in my pom. I just want to call **A**.

If I just specify **A**, I don't get **B**'s and **C**'s dependencies.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you show how you tried that (pom.xml) and furthermore what you like to achieve?

Comment: It will take time to show example poms, so I'll tell you my end goal - I want to get all jars/wars used by my **A** project (and all its sub modules) so I can run some analysis on them.

Comment: If you have a moulti module project where A is your parent of the childs you can use that to get all the information. The question what kind of analysis you would like to run? Sonar ?

Comment: I just want to collect all jars used by the project (all modules) so they can be analysed by a 3rd party tool (I don't care which tool...)